# Getting memory error for graph clustering even for 128 GB of memory. Why?

Tags: python, pandas, graph, cluster-analysis, networkx

I am using **python** language on a Linux server with **128 GB memory**. I am doing graph clustering using **Markov algorithm**. The details of the process are as follows:

```
Graphtype = nx.Graph()
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'source','target', edge_attr='weight', create_using=Graphtype)
```

#### Graph details:

```
Name: 
Type: Graph
Number of nodes: 4533801
Number of edges: 10548751
Average degree:   4.6534
```

#### Is the graph connected?

```
nx.is_connected(G)
False
```

#### Number of connected components

```
print(nx.number_connected_components(G))
7254
```

#### Markov Clustering

```
import markov_clustering as mc
import networkx as nx

matrix = nx.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(Gc) # build the matrix
result = mc.run_mcl(matrix)            # run MCL with default parameters
clusters = mc.get_clusters(result)     # get clusters

MemoryError
```

[image]

Why am I still getting a **memory error** message when trying to extract the clusters? 
What is the issue? How can I go around this?

**UPDATE:**

Reporting results taking into account the comments given.
[image]

Comment: The MemoryError should include a traceback, can you add that to the question?

Comment: added..........

Comment: You've got *two* graphs, `G` and `Gc`. What does `Gc` look like?

Comment: It is the same. I just gave it another name.

Comment: Do you know how much memory you can actually use? Sometimes it is less than system ram. Try `numpy.ndarray(2**32)` which would take about 16GB.

Comment: Are you running a 32 or 64 bit version of Python? Check with `python -c 'import struct; print(struct.calcsize("P") * 8)'`. A 32 bit version will limit you to less than 4 GB of RAM no matter how much the server has.

Comment: Actually it is 64 bit

Comment: That `.copy()` is likely part of the problem. Even if you can represent the full graph, it may be that you can't represent _two copies_ of the full graph without memory issues. That line indicates that the full sparse matrix representing the graph is being copied. How big is that matrix? Is it under half your *usable* memory?

Comment: And looking further up the stack, there's a call to `inflate`. The source for that eventually leads to scikit-learn's [`sklearn.preprocessing.normalize`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/76ef8b0ef07f9c03b97d29a51e1543be7720e85a/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py#L1650) method. The docs for that say that sparse matrices must be in CSR format "to avoid an unnecessary copy". Is your matrix in the correct format?

Comment: I updated the question to include the results where i used one copy of the matrix + the CSR format.

Comment: Try adding `copy=False` to the `normalize` call in  your MCL installation. Maybe the copy is casting the matrix to a dense format under the hood, having 2 of these sparse matrices in memory shouldn't be a problem on a 128GB RAM machine. It's on line 23 in `mcl.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd assume from your code that you're using 32 bit Python, which means that regardless of hardware, you won't be able to make use of more that 4GB of RAM.

Upgrading to a 64 bit Python will let you use up to 16EB of RAM which will allow you to use the additional space you have on a server.

You could save *some* memory by not storing unnecessary variables, and letting python clear out discarded information. From what I can see in these lines of code:

```
matrix = nx.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(Gc) # build the matrix
result = mc.run_mcl(matrix)            # run MCL with default parameters
clusters = mc.get_clusters(result)     # get clusters
```

The 'matrix' and 'result' variables are only used to arrive at 'clusters' so don't theoretically need to be saved. This code should give python permission to clear up a bit of memory:

```
clusters = mc.get_clusters(mc.run_mcl(nx.to_scipy_sparse_matric(Gc)))
```

Obviously, you're sacrificing legibility and elegance of code and it's unlikely that this will free up enough space to solve your issue, but it's worth pointing your attention to just in case.